# Does Windows 10's dictation feature exist on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows

For a client we need the Windows dictation feature available on a Windows Server 2016 terminal server.

I did not find anything regarding this option and how it could be activated, so I was hoping someone would have an answer here.

In the Windows Server 2016 settings I could find one point in the privacy options where the dictation feature is mentioned but I could not find it anywhere else.

`Windows key + H` activates the dictation on a regular workstation but not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing  the Following "Windows Capabilities" (replace fr-FR with your language + culture) ?

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? { $_.Name.Contains( 'fr-FR') }


Name  : Language.Basic~~~fr-FR~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent

Name  : Language.Handwriting~~~fr-FR~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent

Name  : Language.OCR~~~fr-FR~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent

Name  : Language.Speech~~~fr-FR~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent

Name  : Language.TextToSpeech~~~fr-FR~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. All but the handwriting one are installed in the correct language.